# Is there a Perl DBI driver for SQL Server Compact 3.5?

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

Maybe I'm not looking in the right places but I'd like to use SQL Server Compact 3.5 as a back-end for an existing Perl app that uses DBI (on Windows).

I'm looking specifically at SQL Server Compact 3.5 because I'd like to use the existing support for it in [MS Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sync) to get started instead of the SQLite db I'm currently using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen any and since there isn't an ODBC driver for SQL Server Compact your only option is to use DBD::ADO.

Comment: Given the absence of an ODBC driver, this is plausible advice.